# jquery mouse hover scroll the div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a plugin.
There will be logos of my clients and 2 buttons on both ends ,if user will hover on the left button then the logos will move right to left and if hover on right button the logos will move from left to right (till last logo after that stop animation)
i am able to do it by the code below ,but the problem is that after last logo if i again hover on button its shows white space .
same problem with the previous button initially if we hover on button its showing white space .

```
var kiu = $('#cont1').width();
    var screenwidth = $(window).width();
    var realwid = kiu - screenwidth;


        $(".Nextb").hover(function () {
            $('#contS').stop().animate({ 'margin-left': '-=' + realwid }, 4500); 
        }, function () {
            $('#contS').stop().animate();
        });



        $(".Prevb").hover(function () {
            $('#contS').stop().animate({ 'margin-left': '+=' + realwid }, 4500);
        }, function () {
            $('#contS').stop().animate();
        })
```

HTML

```
<div class="cont">

                    <div id="cont1" class=" wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                    <div class="NPrev">

                <span class="Prevb"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></span>
                <span class="Nextb"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                </div>
                        <div class="kk">
                            <div class="ki kk1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="ki kk2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="contS" class="Img_cl1">
                            <div class="col-md-12 fdfll  scroll-left">
                                <a target="_blank" href="http://www.meraevents.com/">
                                    <div class=" cl1 hde ">
                                        <img alt="client" src="img/clients/1.png" />
                                    </div>
                                </a><a target="_blank" href="http://www.appvirality.com/">
                                    <div class=" cl2 hde">
                                        <img alt="client" src="img/clients/2.png" />
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <style>

                                </style>
                                <a target="_blank" href="http://www.customfurnish.com/">
                                    <div class=" cl3 hde ">
                                        <img style="max-width: 120px !important; margin-top: 20px;" alt="client" src="img/clients/3.png" />
                                    </div>
                                </a><a target="_blank" href="http://www.medplusmart.com/home.mart">
                                    <div class="  cl4 hde ">
                                        <img alt="client" src="img/clients/4.png" />
                                    </div>
                                </a><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ishyd.org/">
                                    <div class=" cl5 hde ">
                                        <img alt="client" src="img/clients/5.png" />
                                    </div>
                                </a><a target="_blank" href="http://www.stileeye.com/">
                                    <div class=" cl6 hde ">
                                        <img alt="client" src="img/clients/6.png" />
                                    </div>
                                </a><a target="_blank" href="http://vuego.tv/index.html">
                                    <div class=" cl7 hde ">
                                        <img alt="client" src="img/clients/7.png" />
                                    </div>
                                </a><a target="_blank" href="http://www.veooz.com/">
                                    <div class=" cl8 hde ">
                                        <img alt="client" src="img/clients/8.png" />
                                    </div>
                                </a><a target="_blank" href="http://www.zapevent.com/">
                                    <div class=" cl9 hde ">
                                        <img alt="client" src="img/clients/9.png" />
                                    </div>
                                </a><a target="_blank" href="https://www.doctrz.com/">
                                    <div class=" cl10 hde ">
                                        <img alt="client" src="img/clients/10.png" />
                                    </div>
                                </a><a target="_blank" href="http://reveye.in/">
                                    <div class=" cl11 hde ">
                                        <img style="margin-top: 0px !important;" alt="client" src="img/clients/11.png" />
                                    </div>
                                </a><a target="_blank" href="http://www.leonia.in/">
                                    <div class=" hde cl12 ">
                                        <img style="margin-top: 0px !important;" alt="client" src="img/clients/12.png" />
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have attached image of output please help me .
[image]

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/#quickdemo  is this the effect you are going for?

Comment: if we hover on next button the logos slide from left to right till last logo